# Digital Ocean Spaces CDN - duplicate files to all regions automatically

Tags: digital-ocean, cdn

I've set up a single DO 'Space' in the Europe region and I want to create identical spaces across all the other available regions. Ideally I would be able to just upload a file once, to one of the buckets, and it would automatically duplicate and sync with all the other regions. The end goal is a global CDN of sorts.

I haven't been able to find any solutions specific to DO which aren't just upload to all regions manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital Ocean doesn't have a built-in way to replicate a bucket across regions.  You'll have to write a script to do this yourself.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure of the reason you want to do this to *all* regions, but if you're trying to use Spaces as a CDN, there actually is a free CDN you can enable for your buckets, which is global already.  It's always good to have a copy of your stuff in multiple regions, but replicating to all sounds like overkill to me, for most tasks.

Comment: So when I selected the Europe region, it's stored in all their datacenters in Europe, but will be cached worldwide?

Comment: @BenjaminSommer Suppose you create a bucket in AMS3.  Your data is primarily stored only in AMS3 (not all of Europe).  But if you use the CDN with your bucket, your files will be cached on the edge, worldwide.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for helping me understand this :)